# componentWillReceiveProps/willUpdate not triggering on specific prop change (mapStateToProps)

Tags: reactjs, redux

Strange problem. Basically, my lifecycle events aren't triggering in response to a specific prop change. This is a React/Redux app, and here's the rough hierarchy:

Components:
Dashboard
--Export
--Analytics
----CreateGraphsDialog

Reducers:
DashboardReducer
ExportReducer
AnalyticsReducer
index

Actions:
Dashboard
Export
Analytics

The prop in question is changed with a select field that is present in the Dashboard, Export, and Analytics components. It's updated with the Dashboard action and DashboardReducer, and accessed via mapStateToProps. When I try to trigger the lifecycle events, such as componentWillReceiveProps or componentWillUpdate, from the main dashboard page, it works perfectly. But trying to access them from either of the child pages, Export or Analytics, fails. The prop updates, but its update doesn't trigger the events.

For note, the prop/item in question is a string, so I don't thing this is an immutability problem... unless immutability in other reducers could be causing the problem. It's also worth noting that the component *is* updating in response to these prop changes, and the prop is changed... it's just the lifecycle events that aren't triggering.

Here's some code:

Dashboard Action

```
import axios from 'axios';
const qs = require('querystring-browser');

export const GOT_INVESTIGATIONS = 'got_investigations';
export const INVESTIGATIONS_ERROR = 'investigations_error';
export const SAVED_INVESTIGATION = 'saved_investigation';

export function getInvestigationsAction() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      let jwtlocal = localStorage.getItem('user');

      let uri;
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        uri = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/jwtInvestigations'
      } else {
        uri = 'https://test.teamscope.co/jwtInvestigations'
      }

      const res = await axios.get(`${uri}`, {headers: {'TS-JWT': jwtlocal}});

      dispatch({type: GOT_INVESTIGATIONS, payload: res.data.investigations})
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      dispatch({
        type: INVESTIGATIONS_ERROR,
        payload: 'Error retrieving investigations. Please try again, or contact an administrator.'
      })
    }
  }
}

export function saveInvestigationAction(invest) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      console.log("InvestInSave:", invest)
      dispatch({type: SAVED_INVESTIGATION, payload: invest})
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("SAVED_INVESTIGATION ERROR")
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
}
```

DashboardReducer:

```
import { GOT_INVESTIGATIONS, INVESTIGATIONS_ERROR, SAVED_INVESTIGATION } from '../actions/dashboard';

const initialState = {

};

export default function(state=initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GOT_INVESTIGATIONS:
      return { ...state, investsData: action.payload, investsError: undefined };
    case INVESTIGATIONS_ERROR:
      return { ...state, investsError: action.payload };
    case SAVED_INVESTIGATION:
      return { ...state, savedInvest: action.payload };
  }
  return state;
}
```

Analytics Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import Table, { TableBody, TableCell, TableHead, TableRow } from 'material-ui/Table';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import CreateGraphsDialog from './CreateGraphsDialog';

import Cached from 'material-ui-icons/Cached';

import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { getSavedGraphsAction, deleteGraphsAction, getGraphAction } from '../../actions/analytics';

import compose from 'recompose/compose';

const Highcharts = require('highcharts');
require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);
const ReactHighcharts = require('react-highcharts');

class Analytics extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props.getSavedGraphsAction(this.props.investigation);
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
        console.log(this.props.investigation)
        console.log(nextProps.investigation)
        //These consoles only fire if a *different* prop is changed, and even then they only ever show the same value for each.
        if (this.props.investigation && nextProps.investigation) {
            if (this.props.investigation !== nextProps.investigation) {
                console.log("!")
                //This console never fires.
                this.props.getSavedGraphsAction(nextProps.investigation)
            }
        }
    }

    refreshGraphs = () => {
        this.props.graphData.forEach((graph) => {
            this.props.getGraphAction(graph.values);
        });
    };


    render() {
        let graphs = null;
        if (this.props.graphData.length > 0) {
            console.log("graphs:", this.props.graphData)
            this.props.graphData.forEach((graph, i) => {
                if (graph.values.chartType !== 'basic') {
                    graph.config.exporting = {
                        buttons: {
                          deleteButton: {
                            enabled: true,
                            text: "Delete",
                            onclick: () => { this.props.deleteGraphsAction(graph.values.identifier) }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                }
            })
            graphs = (
                <div>
                {this.props.graphData.map((graph) =>
                    { return graph.values.chartType === 'basic' ?    
                        <div className="graphs"> 
                          <Table className={this.props.classes.table}>
                            <TableHead>
                              <TableRow>
                                <TableCell>Survey Name</TableCell>
                                <TableCell numeric>Minimum</TableCell>
                                <TableCell numeric>Maximum</TableCell>
                                <TableCell numeric>Mean</TableCell>
                                <TableCell numeric>Standard Deviation</TableCell>
                                <TableCell numeric>Variance</TableCell>
                                <TableCell numeric>Count</TableCell>
                                <TableCell><Button primary onClick={() => this.props.deleteGraphsAction(graph.values.identifier)}>Delete</Button></TableCell>
                              </TableRow>
                            </TableHead>
                            <TableBody>
                              <TableRow>
                                <TableCell>{graph.config.surveyTitle}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell numeric>{graph.config.stats.min}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell numeric>{graph.config.stats.max}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell numeric>{graph.config.stats.mean}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell numeric>{graph.config.stats.stdDev}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell numeric>{graph.config.stats.var}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell numeric>{graph.config.stats.count}</TableCell>
                              </TableRow>
                            </TableBody>
                          </Table>
                        </div>
                        : <div className="graphs">
                            <ReactHighcharts config={graph.config}/>
                          </div> }
                )}
                </div>
            )
        } else if (!this.props.investigation) {
            graphs = "Please select an investigation from the top right selection menu.";
        } else {
            graphs = null;
        }
            return (
                <div>
                    <CreateGraphsDialog/>
                    <Button className={this.props.classes.refresh} onClick={this.refreshGraphs}>
                        Refresh <Cached/>
                    </Button>
                    {graphs}
                </div>
            );
        }
}


const styles = {
 margin: 15,
  table: {
    minWidth: 700,
  },
  refresh: {
  },
  graphs: {
  }
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return { 
    investigation: state.dashboard.savedInvest,
    graphData: state.analytics.graphData,
    graphError: state.analytics.graphError
  };
}


export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps, {getSavedGraphsAction, deleteGraphsAction, getGraphAction}),
  withStyles(styles)
)(Analytics);
```

--------------UPDATE---------------

I just tried this with a brand new component, without all the extra stuff in it. It's a child component, just like Analytics. It has the same problem. Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { getAuditsAction } from '../../actions/auditTrail';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import compose from 'recompose/compose';

class AuditTrail extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.props.getAuditsAction(this.props.investigation)
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
        //These don't get called at all, since there aren't any other props to muddy the waters.
        console.log(this.props.investigation);
        console.log(nextProps.investigation);
    }

    render() {

        let notification;

        if (!this.props.investigation) {
            notification = "Please select an investigation from the top right selection menu.";
        } else if (this.props.auditError) {
            notification = this.props.auditError;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                {notification}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const styles = {
    formContainer: {
        width: '30%'
    }
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return { 
    investigation: state.dashboard.savedInvest,
    audits: state.auditTrail.auditData,
    auditError: state.auditTrail.auditError
  };
}

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps, { getAuditsAction }),
  withStyles(styles)
)(AuditTrail);
```

Comment: Did u console  props in `componentWillReceiveProps ` of Analytics component?What it showing.Please make some comment in code where . u not getting  expected behviuor

Comment: Will do that now.

Comment: Done. Please see my comments in `componentWillUpdate`

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

From provided code snippet

**DashboardReducer :**

```
case GOT_INVESTIGATIONS : return {
  ...state,
  investsData: action.payload,
  investsError: undefined
};
```

You are doing only one level of shallow copy. Instead you should do 
  state update like this.

```
return Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state), {
  investsData: action.payload,
  investsError: undefined
}));
```

Please refer official documentation  [`Redux#ImmutableUpdatePatterns`](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html)

Comment: Doing this doesn't change anything. I changed all my reducers to using this style of reducer (Object.assign instead of spread) and especially the places where I'm using multiple values, but I'm having the same problem. The prop from the other reducer just doesn't trigger the event. It rerenders, and therefore calls the function I have set up, which triggers other props, and THOSE rerender, but that specific prop does not call the lifecycle event. Is it because its from a different reducer maybe?